# Matlab: How to specify Coupon frequency for Interest Rate Swap

Tags: matlab, quantitative-finance, computational-finance

Although I believe that Quantitative Finance Forum is more relevant for this question, as this is far more popular, I'll let myself to ask same question here.

I'm trying to price an interest rate swap and would like to change the default coupon payment frequency from 1 a year to 2 or 4 a year. I'm using

```
Price = swapbyzero(RateSpec, LegRate, i, Maturity, 'Principal', Principal);
```

and tried

```
Price = swapbyzero(RateSpec, LegRate, i, Maturity, 'Principal', Principal,'Period',2);
```

where 'Period' is a valid option when pricing bond using

```
prbyzero
```

I'm using matlab 2013a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional input pair is `'LegReset'` and set it to  `[n n]`, where `n` is the frequency of payments.